# sidebar scroll down to section

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar with a list of items where users can go to particular pages. What I'd like to do is to click on the element and scroll down to the section but it has to move to a section only when clicking on this button.

The problem is that my `a` tag looks like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'article_list' %}">
    <li class="nav_list">go to section</li>
</a>
```

So I am not able to [follow this pattern](https://css-tricks.com/need-to-scroll-to-the-top-of-the-page/):

```
<html>
  <body>
     <a id="top"></a>
      <!-- the entire document -->
      <a href="#top">Jump to top of page</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Because as you can see `a` tag is already referring to `article_list`.

I am using Django 3.2 and Bootstrap 5.

Any advise on how this can be easly implemented will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use that you've to set a **anchor** tag href reference to your top element id. You can do like this you can create one more anchor tag

```
<a href="#top">Scroll Up</a>
```

or you can create any tag *eg.(`<span>`)* and add event listner

```
<span onclick="ScrollUp()">Scroll Up</span>
```

---

```
function ScrollUp(){
  window.scroll({
    top: 0, 
    left: 0, 
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

you can use on `onmouseover="ScrollUp()"` for scrollin up without clicking on element user just have to hover on it but it's less user friendly I guess

Comment: thanks for the answer but how can I open the page and then scroll down?

Comment: You've to add id to an element at the bottom of the page and then in your anchor tag add this `<a href="{% url 'article_list' %}#down" >`